# Selenium.UnhandledAlertException: C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm running the C# tests from remote web driver for an application. I used page refresh after it's redirected to a different application's page to make sure the page exists, but when it refreshes the page, it throws the following error at times:

> OpenQA.Selenium.UnhandledAlertException : Unexpected modal dialog (text: To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier.): To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier.

How can I avoid this in Selenium?

```
public static void Continue(IWebDriver instance)
{
    SeleniumCommand.ClickElementById(instance, "Continue");
    instance.Navigate().Refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `UnhandledAlertException` is caused when you try to perform an action, such as a click, when there is an alert box present on the page.

You can dismiss the alert:

```
instance.SwitchTo().Alert().Dismiss();
```

Or accept the alert, pending your application:

```
instance.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
```

Note: Both examples above should be placed only after the alert box displays and before another action is performed.

---

If the alert is displaying intermittently, you can also wrap the call in a `try`/`catch`:

```
try
{
    instance.SwitchTo().Alert().Dismiss();
}
catch (NoAlertPresentException)
{
    // handle this exception, or just ignore it
}
```

Comment: I tried using this and it threw this error :
OpenQA.Selenium.NoAlertPresentException : No alert is present
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteTargetLocator.Alert()

Comment: Updated my answer, make sure to place the code only after the alert box displays and before another action is performed.

Comment: Thank you. I used try/catch, as the alert is intermittent. But I'm not sure if the test case will proceed forward after it ignores this alert, as the test case is expecting some values and page refresh would wipe off those values. Anyways, I wasn't able to see the alert in my testing. Will keep posted if I face any issues in future.

Comment: The fact things like this are necessary is why I really dislike any form of UI testing! The horror...